# HttpClient and Visual Studio Extension Project

Tags: c#, vsix

I was working on a VS Extension Project, which required me to use HttpClient. However, I am running into following issue when attempting to create an instance of HttpClient.

"'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies."

Could someone guide me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Http API that is built into .NET - like HttpWebRequest

Comment: Hi Thanks Erik. That worked. Could you please help me understand why HttpClient doesn't quite work ?

Comment: See my comment - you must add a Binding redirect, and an extension cannot write to develop devenv.exe.config - and adding binding redirects in code in VS is not recommended

Comment: Thanks Erik. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you do require the binding redirect.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Binding redirects via config is not possible in a VS extension